# Div height works on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with visualitation between Firefox and Chrome and I don't know why, I try some things but it works fine in firefox, but height size of article don't work as I expected:

```css
 *{
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 #main {
    height: 80%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:         flex;
    flex-flow: row;
 }
 #main section {
  background: #CFC;
  flex: 3 1 60%;
  order: 2;
 }
 #main nav {
  background: #CCF;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 1;
 }
 #main aside {
  background: #CCF;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 3;
 }
 header, footer {
  display: block;
  min-height: 10%;
  background: #FC6;
 }
 #header, #footer {
  display: block;
  min-height: 10%;
  background: #CCC;
 }
 #article{
  display: block;
  height:80%;
 }
 #content{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
  <header>&lt;header&gt;
  </header>
  <div id="main">
   <nav>&lt;nav&gt;
   </nav>
   <section>
    <div id="content">
     <div id="header">&lt;header&gt;
     </div>
     <div id="article">&lt;article&gt;
     </div>
     <div id="footer">&lt;footer&gt;
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <aside>&lt;aside&gt;
   </aside>
  </div>
  <footer>&lt;footer&gt;
  </footer>
```

Comment: off topic: you don't need to have `px` if something is `0`, eg: `margin: 0;` and for border you can `border: none;`

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: the div #content don't have the full size of parent in chrome, has the minimum size of inside divs, but in firefox it has (as I want)

Comment: You can see here: https://googledrive.com/host/0B_BSLmfWdnO5Wk1SZjFmMTY5VWs/  and what I want to get is this:    https://googledrive.com/host/0B_BSLmfWdnO5Wk1SZjFmMTY5VWs/download.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `height:100%` to `#main section` like this:

```css
    *{
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
 #main {
    height: 80%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:         flex;
    flex-flow: row;
 }
 #main section {
  background: #CFC;
  flex: 3 1 60%;
  order: 2;
  height:100%;
 }
 #main nav {
  background: #CCF;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 1;
 }
 #main aside {
  background: #CCF;
  flex: 1 6 20%;
  order: 3;
 }
 header, footer {
  display: block;
  min-height: 10%;
  background: #FC6;
 }
 #header, #footer {
  display: block;
  min-height: 10%;
  background: #CCC;
 }
 #article{
  display: block;
  height:80%;
 }
 #content{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
 }
```

```html
  <header>&lt;header&gt;
  </header>
  <div id="main">
   <nav>&lt;nav&gt;
   </nav>
   <section>
    <div id="content">
     <div id="header">&lt;header&gt;
     </div>
     <div id="article">&lt;article&gt;
     </div>
     <div id="footer">&lt;footer&gt;
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <aside>&lt;aside&gt;
   </aside>
  </div>
  <footer>&lt;footer&gt;
  </footer>
```